# How to crop digital elevation .tif file by coordinates with GDAL

Tags: gdal, clip

I am using SASplanet to download satellite imagery. It has coordinates like in the photo.

I want to crop larger downloaded DEM .tif file of Austria to that same coordinates, so cropped dem file will match satellite imagery. I am trying in gdal, but I do not know how to do it yet. I think some longitude values(Y) from SASplanet are too high.

I tried:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 461561 5280248 482689 5261309 austria.tif austria_croped.tif
```

I got way smaller file like I would expect from cropped image, but was completely black with no visual info. I think I did not do it correctly, can someone correct the input line?

I also tried:

```
C:\OSGeo\bin>gdal_translate -projwin 47d40'28.1220"E 14d29'16.4671"N 47d30'17.9454"E 14d46'12.4278"N src_dataset austria.tif dst_dataset austria_cropped.tif
ERROR 4: dst_dataset: No such file or directory
```

[image: satellite coordinates]

Gdal info on the DEM map of Austria gives that results.

[image]

Comment: Read https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-projwin and consider in which coordinate system you want to give the coordinates. For degree units gdal awaits decimal degrees and not something like `47d40'28.1220`.

Comment: I tried multiple possible variants, it didn't work. I am still waiting for simple line, which would save me days or work.

Comment: Please tell us the `<ulx> <uly> <lrx> <lry>` coordinates that you want to use, and in which crs they are expressed.

Comment: E14°29'37.8100" N47°40'45.7600" E14°46'27.8100" N47°29'47.6500"    crs: SASPlanet says WGS 84 / Geographic,  Projection Mercator(Google Maps, OSM, Bing) / EPSG: 3857 That are the coordinates from the satellite imagery.